# Can HttpContext.Items be access in .net Core DLL?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using a .Net Core 2.1 app (Web API) .

I'm able to access `HttpContext.Items["_logId"]` within a controller , via:

```
HttpContext.Items["_logId"] = generalRequest.LogId;
```

But when I try to access it via .Net Core class Library DLL :

```
 public class GeneralRequest
    {
        public string LogId => HttpContext.Items["_logId"];
        public string Body { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

I get an error :

> Cannot access non-static property Items

[image]

In earlier (non .Net Core) versions, we could access Items in a static manner.

**Question**

The whole point of adding to  `Items`, is so that we will be able to read them everywhere along the request.

How can I read `HttpContext.Items` from a class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject via your DI framework or asp.net cores own framework in the constructor:

```
public class GeneralRequest 
{
    public GeneralRequest(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.LogId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["_logId"];
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add this to your Startup.cs

```
 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: `GeneralRequest ` is a response custom type that I must `new` by myself .... Must I inject `IHttpContextAccessor ` in order to solve it ?

Comment: I guess constructor injection is the way you go. If you do not want to do this, you can always resolve to reading the logId in your web application and pass the concrete value to your GeneralRequest class. That would save you a dependency